# Redis ZRANGEBYSCORE strange behaviour

Tags: redis

I'm using redis 2.6. I've faced with strange behavior of `ZRANGEBYSCORE` function. 
I have a sorted set with a length of about a few million elements. 
Something like this:

```
10 marry 
15 john 
25 bob 
...
```

So compare to queries:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE longset 25 50 LIMIT 0 20  works like a charm, it takes milliseconds
ZRANGEBYSCORE longset 25 50             this one hangs up for a minutes!!
```

All elements which I'm intrested in are in the first hundred of the set.
I think that there's no need to scan elements with weight greater than "50"
because it is SORTED set.

Please explain how redis scans sorted sets and why there is such a big difference between these two queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the best things about Redis, IMO, is that you can check the time complexity of each command in the docs. The docs for [zrangebyscore](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) specifies:

> **Time complexity**: O(log(N)+M) with N being the number of elements in the sorted set and M the number of elements being returned. If M is constant (e.g. always asking for the first 10 elements with LIMIT), you can consider it O(log(N)).
>
> [...]
>
> Keep in mind that if `offset` is large, the sorted set needs to be traversed for `offset` elements before getting to the elements to return, which can add up to **O(N)** time complexity.

This means that if you know that you only need a certain number of items, and specify a `LIMIT offset count`, if `offset` is (close to) `0`, you can consider it **O(log(N))**, but if the returned number of items is high (or the offset is high), it can be considered **O(N)**.